# Which linux browser + password manager can ask for master password every time

Tags: linux, password, browser

I want to find a Linux browser that can store passwords ant doesn't cache the master password. That is, I want to be asked for the master password every time a password is to be filled.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just use a password manager instead of the browser?

Comment: Yes, that's an option. Sorry for not been clear. I´m finally using Firefox PassFF plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `signon.masterPasswordReprompt.timeout_ms` (in milliseconds) variable in Firefox to get the same result. It's 900 seconds by default, i.e. Firefox will ask your master password 15 minutes after you last used it but you can set it to something low like 60 seconds, i.e. `60000`.

I've heard that the BitWarden password manager has this option but I've never used it.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like the answer, but unfortunately doesn't seem to work. Tested after modifying the parameter and restart firefox. Keeps offering passwords after the timeout without reprompt of the master password.